# Jade экранирование атрибутов (Как задать атрибут для _.template)?

Tags: express, backbone.js, jade, underscore.js

Есть некий шаблон, который сначала рендерится из jade в html на сервере, а потом в него добавляется некоторая информация на клиенте с помощью `_.template`. Не получается задать data-атрибут вида `<%= id%>`. Вот как я пытался это сделать:

**1**. Шаблон jade:

```
.class(data-id="<%= id %>")
    b <%= id %>
```

Рендериться в:

```
<div class="class" data-id="&lt;%= id %&gt;">
    <b><%= id %></b>
</div>
```

И соответственно: `_.template()` =>

```
<div class="class" data-id="<%= id %>">
    <b>349684</b>
</div>
```

**2**.

```
-my_var = '<%= id %>'
.class(data-id='#{my_var}')
    b <%= id %>
```

=> см. первый вариант

**3**.

```
-my_var = '<%= id %>'
.class(data-id=!{my_var})
    b <%= id %>
```

=>

```
<div class="class" data-id="!{my_var}">
    <b><%= id %></b>
</div>
```

**4**.

```
-my_var = '<%= id %>'
.class(data-id=#{my_var})
    b <%= id %>
```

=> Unexpected token ILLEGAL

**5**.

```
-my_var = '<%= id %>'
.class(data-id=!{my_var})
    b <%= id %>
```

=>

```
<div class="class">
    <b><%= id %></b>
</div>
```

Как правильно обойти экранирование в jade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div(escaped="<code>")
div(unescaped!="<code>")
```

=>

```
<div escaped="&lt;code&gt;"></div>
<div unescaped="<code>"></div>
```